# How do I copy a row to another table in MySQL using Jquery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a **main_list** table in MySQL and I would like to copy a specific row to another **my_list** table. At the moment I am using DataTables and in my 4th column I have an "Add" button.

**JS file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#items').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"items-data.php", // json datasource
                    type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                    error: function(){  // error handling
                        $(".items-grid-error").html("");
                        $("#items-grid").append('<tbody class="items-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                        $("#items-grid_processing").css("display","none");
                        }
                },
                "columnDefs": [ {
                "targets": 0,
                "data": null ,
                "render": function ( data ) {
                return '<a href=//'+data[ 3 ]+' target="_blank">'+data[ 0 ]+'</a>';
                }
                },
                { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 3 ] },
                { "sClass": "add", "targets": [ 4 ] },
                {
                "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Add</button>"

                } ]
            } );

    $('#items-grid tbody').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var myData = 'addToList';

    jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST", 
          url: "add.php", 
          dataType:"text", 
          data:myData, 
          success:function(response){
            alert('Success');
          },
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
          }
          });

    } );

        } );
```

So I can't figure out what kind of data should I send via the AJAX POST so I can trigger the MySQL query. Ideally it would be the row id that somehow I should get from MySQL Table. How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
    //include db configuration file
    include_once("connection.php");


    // add item to my list 


    if(isset($_POST['addToList'])){

        $sql = " INSERT INTO my_list (item_name, item_detail, item_location, item_website) ";
        $sql.= " SELECT item_name, item_detail, item_location, item_website ";
        $sql.= " FROM main_list ";
        $sql.= " WHERE id = 20 ";

       if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
           echo "Record copied successfully";
       } else {
           echo "Error copying record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
       }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Send the id of database table row back via ajax.

Comment: Is it really neccassary to have the exact same data in two different tables?

Comment: I am trying to build a favorites system later on, but I would like to take it one step at a time. The goal would be that the user will click the add button and copy the row to his list.

Comment: Well the thing about databases is that if you get the design right first up life becomes a lot easier later on. Changing tables later is very difficult. Consider creating table called favourites that merely stores the user id and the item id. Think about it, if 100 users favourite each item your database size is going to explode.

Comment: The structure of the database would than be: main_list, user_list and favourites_list. So If I have 10 items and 10 users, and all the users add all the items, the favourites_list table would be 100.

Comment: Correct but the size of the whole database would be much smaller. Also what if a change was made to an entry in the main_list table? With your current design the copy would be out of sync

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful in understanding the structure of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is to simplify the problem. This doesn't have to be a jquery/php combined problem. You can first right PHP code that executes the database queries. You can test it visually by passing in different parametes in the URL. Once you get it working, it's a trivial matter to plug that url into your javascript code to have them working together.

The url parameter can be the primary key of the record. You've got it hard coded at the moment `$sql.= " WHERE id = 20 ";` it should change it to `$sql.= " WHERE id = 20 ";` and it's value come for $_POST

Comment: Thank you, but how do I get the corresponding id for each row from MySQL? Should I have a different button/query for each row like button_1, button_2 that should get id 1/2 from the database ?

Comment: Generally a table should have a primary key. For fastest queries this would be a numeric column. It's very hard to generalize but when you don't have any natural integer fields in your table a common practice is to use autoincrement fields and mark it as primary https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: You don't need a host of buttons (well you can do it that way if you want to) but the usual strategy is to asign the primary key or something based on it as the html id attribute for the row and use that in ajax.

Comment: Regarding your last comments I found this on the datatables website: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html This might be a step closer to my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

i think that it would be enough if you just include the id of the row you want to copy in the ajax request.
After checking the query you have included, i think that it needs to be refactored. It would be better to have a query like :

```
insert into my_list (
    item_name,
    item_detail,
    item_location,
    item_website
) values (
    select
        item_name,
        item_detail,
        item_location,
        item_website
    from
        main_list
    where
        id = (the id from ajax request)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, now I just have to resolve how I query the id for each row, I guess.

Comment: What query do you use in order to retrieve the data from the db in the first place?